# Взять из выбранного input radio значение id и использовать его в скрипте вместо названия класса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть календарь, состоящий из radio-кнопок и textarea, модальное окно, а также 2 кнопки, которые переносят textarea от radio-кнопки в модальное окно и обратно.

Как сделать чтобы это работало с одним textarea я сообразил.

Но не понимаю как сделать так чтобы какую дату в календаре выбрал, та textarea и переместилась в модальное окно, и обратно.

UPD: Проще говоря я не знаю как из выбранного `<input type="radio" id="date2022-10-29">` взять значение id и использовать его в скрипте вот здесь `$(".date2022-10-28 textarea")` вместо  `date2022-10-28`.

Поможете?

```js
    // Перенос заметки в модальное окно и обратно
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#note').click(function() {
            $(".date2022-10-28 textarea").appendTo("#notedText");
        }); 
        $('#modalCloseBtn').click(function() {
            $("#notedText textarea").appendTo(".date2022-10-28");
        }); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Календарь -->
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="date2022-10-28" name="date" onchange="sync(this)" value="2022-10-28">
    <label class="custom-control-label border border-white bg-light text-dark" for="date2022-10-28">28</label>
    <div class="d-none date2022-10-28">
        <textarea class="form-control rounded-0 border-0 h-100" id="note-2022-10-28">Заметка за 28-ое</textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="date2022-10-29" name="date" onchange="sync(this)" value="2022-10-29">
    <label class="custom-control-label border border-white bg-light text-dark" for="date2022-10-29">29</label>
    <div class="d-none date2022-10-29">
        <textarea class="form-control rounded-0 border-0 h-100" id="note-2022-10-29">Заметка за 29-ое</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ... и так 365 раз -->

<hr>

<!-- Кнопка вызова модального окна -->
<button type="button" id="note" class="btn btn-light btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#noted-modal">Перенести заметку в модальное окно</button>

<hr>

<!-- Модальное окно -->
<div class="modal fade" id="noted-modal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="noted-Label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header pt-2 pb-2">
        <button type="button" id="modalCloseBtn" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Вернуть заметку обратно</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body p-0">
        <div class="h-100 collapse multi-collapse show" id="notedText">
            Место назначения для textarea<br/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ПС: я задавал это вопрос, но другими с другим смыслом. Вопрос к пользователям, знающим stackoverflow сообщество. Как правильно поступить с предыдущим вопросом, удалить или пускай будет?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463708/

Comment: [Почитайте](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-radio-button/), тут используется чистый javascript, думаю, должно быть понятно. Но берёт не id, а value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function checkedInput() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  for (let inp of inputs) {
    if (inp.checked) return inp.id;
  }
  return false
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#note').click(function() {
    let date = checkedInput();
    if (date) {
      let textarea = '.' + date + ' textarea';
    $(textarea).appendTo("#notedText");
    }
  });
  $('#modalCloseBtn').click(function() {
    let date = checkedInput();
    if (date) {
      let textarea = '.' + date;
      $("#notedText textarea").appendTo(textarea);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Календарь -->
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="date2022-10-28" name="date" value="2022-10-28">
  <label class="custom-control-label border border-white bg-light text-dark" for="date2022-10-28">28</label>
  <div class="d-none date2022-10-28">
    <textarea class="form-control rounded-0 border-0 h-100" id="note-2022-10-28">Заметка за 28-ое</textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="date2022-10-29" name="date" value="2022-10-29">
  <label class="custom-control-label border border-white bg-light text-dark" for="date2022-10-29">29</label>
  <div class="d-none date2022-10-29">
    <textarea class="form-control rounded-0 border-0 h-100" id="note-2022-10-29">Заметка за 29-ое</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ... и так 365 раз -->

<hr>

<!-- Кнопка вызова модального окна -->
<button type="button" id="note" class="btn btn-light btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#noted-modal">Перенести заметку в модальное окно</button>

<hr>

<!-- Модальное окно -->
<div class="modal fade" id="noted-modal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="noted-Label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header pt-2 pb-2">
        <button type="button" id="modalCloseBtn" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Вернуть заметку обратно</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body p-0">
        <div class="h-100 collapse multi-collapse show" id="notedText">
          Место назначения для textarea<br/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Решение прикольное, но скрипт будет большой: 365 дней * 50 лет = 18 250 дополнительных строк. Может есть способ изменять клас в $(".date2022-10-28 textarea") в зависимости от выбранной radio-кнопки?

Comment: В id кнопки ведь указана дата - подставляйте оттуда в id textarea...

Comment: Да да, вот именно в этом и моя проблема, я не знаю как из выбранного ```<input type="radio" id="date2022-10-29">``` взять значение id и использовать его в скрипте вот здесь ```$(".date2022-10-28 textarea")``` вместо  ```date2022-10-28```.

Comment: Сделал с подстановкой...

Comment: Круто, очень круто! Спасибо за помощь. Я и не знал что можно совмещать js и jQuery )

Answer (score 2):

так сойдёт? :3

```css
form{display: grid;}
textarea:not(:target){display: none;}
```

```html
<form>
<input type='date' onchange='window.location.hash = "#x" + this.value;'>

<textarea id='x2022-11-01'>x2022-11-01</textarea>
<textarea id='x2022-11-02'>x2022-11-02</textarea>
<textarea id='x2022-11-03'>x2022-11-03</textarea>
<textarea id='x2022-11-04'>x2022-11-04</textarea>

<input type='submit' value='ok'>
</form>
```

---

а вообще использовать 100500 по сути идентичных textarea отличающихся только содержимым... ну такое себе... уж лучше один textarea и заменять его содержимое, а сами заметки хранить в json объекте, который потом можно будет отправить по XHR например, буквально одним запросом.

```js
var get = function(el){return document.getElementById(el);}
var notes = {
'2022-11-01': '01',
'2022-11-02': '02',
'2022-11-03': '03',
'2022-11-04': '04'
};
```

```css
form{display: grid}
```

```html
<form>
<input id='date' type='date' onchange='get("note").value = notes[this.value];'>
<textarea id='note'></textarea>
<input type='button' value='save' onclick='notes[get("date").value] = get("note").value'>
</form>
```

> как поступить с предыдущим вопросом

если там не дали какой-то полезной инфы, удалить конечно. если дали, сначала копируешь её сюда в виде ответа или в сам топик с указанием автора честности ради(вдруг кому пригодится), а уже после удаляешь тот топик.

а вообще плодить дубли нехорошо. если вопрос изменился, просто редактируй исходный топик с пометками "UPD"

Comment: Уже выбрал ответ. Спасибо, Вы натолкнули меня на интересные идеи, у Вас оригинальные решения. За совет с топиком тоже спасибо, уже удалил.

Comment: @Юра всегда пожалуйста =)